# Getting error syntaxError: JSON.parse while fetch data from geoserver

Tags: reactjs, geoserver

I am trying to get the WFS from the localhost geoserver and hangle the respond using GeoJson in leaflet. However, when I try to fetch the data, I get the `syntaxError: JSON.parse`. Here is the code:

```
   componentDidMount() {
     fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ws/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ws:example&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json', {
     mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res.json()));
   }
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The exception has told you the returned json js not a valid json. You can print the json string to see where goes wrong.

Comment: GeoServer will return it's error message as XML (by default) so if something goes wrong with your request you will see that error